# Restructure a javascript Array of Objects for Ecommerce categories and subcategories

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, javascript-objects, e-commerce

**Input**

```
let categories =[
{id:1, name:'Electronics', parentId:''},
{id:2, name:'Devices', parentId:1},
{id:3, name:'Mobile Phones', parentId:2},
{id:4, name:'TV', parentId:2},
{id:5, name:'Accessories', parentId:1},
{id:6, name:'Beauty', parentId:''},
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
let categories =[
 {id:1, name:'Electronics', parentId:'', subCategories:[
   {id:2, name:'Devices', parentId:1, subCategories:[
     {id:3, name:'Mobile Phones', parentId:2},
     {id:4, name:'TV', parentId:2}}
    ]
   },
   {id:5, name:'Accessories', parentId:1}
  ]
 },
 {id:6, name:'Beauty',parentId:''}
]
```

**Explanation**

So above in **Input** array

> **id:1** and **id:6** has no parentId. That means they are the root categories in **Expected Output**.
>
> **id:2** and **id:5** has **parentId:1**. That means they are
> subcategories of **id:1** and goes into the subCategories array of **id:1**.
>
> **id:3** and **id:4** has **parentId:2**. That means they are subcategories of **id:2** and goes into the subCategories array of **id:2**.

and there could be more nested subCategories.

**for example**

A new object **id:7** can have a **parentId:4**.So it is a subCategory of **id:4** and goes into the subCategories array of **id:4**

Comment: is the array sorted (parent comes before children)? what goes wrong?

Comment: No.array is not sorted (children can come before parent).what goes wrong is I couldn't restructure the array like expected output above. Tried many ways and ended up with nothing. will be super helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You could build a tree with all related pairs children/parent, parent/children and return the nodes with no parent `''` as tree.

```js
const
    categories = [{ id: 1, name: 'Electronics', parentId: '' }, { id: 2, name: 'Devices', parentId: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'Mobile Phones', parentId: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'TV', parentId: 2 }, { id: 5, name: 'Accessories', parentId: 1 }, { id: 6, name: 'Beauty', parentId: '' }],
    tree = categories
        .reduce((t, o) => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            ((t[o.parentId] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);
            return t;
        }, {})
        ['']
        .children;

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine in every case. Though I had some compatibility issues for my @babel config.Initially didn't had the support for nullish coalescing operator in my react js application. Installed "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6" this devDependency and added it in plugins array of node-modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to create helper `catObj` where key is the id and value is the item of categories. Next use `forEach` loop to conditionally push sub-categories or root-categories to the adequate array based on the existence of `parentCat`.

```js
let categories =[
  {id:1, name:'Electronics', parentId:''},
  {id:2, name:'Devices', parentId:1},
  {id:3, name:'Mobile Phones', parentId:2},
  {id:4, name:'TV', parentId:2},
  {id:5, name:'Accessories', parentId:1},
  {id:6, name:'Beauty', parentId:''},
];

const makeTree = (cats) => {

  const catObj = {}, rootCats = [];

  cats.map((cat) => (catObj[cat.id] = { ...cat }))
  .forEach((cat) => {
    const parentCat = catObj[cat.parentId];
    if (parentCat) {
       parentCat.subCategories = parentCat.subCategories || [];
       parentCat.subCategories.push(cat);
     } else {
       rootCats.push(cat);
    }
  });

  return rootCats;
}



const catTree = makeTree(categories);
console.log(catTree);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer as it is more readable and beginner friendly.